# How to trigger a prompt redraw when the terminal window size changes?

Tags: bash, prompt, readline, window

So I created a trap to check if the change is being registered:

```
trap 'echo $COLUMNS' WINCH
```

And the change is indeed reflected. But my prompt is not redrawn, neither from re-issuing the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` or by printing `$PS1`. So now I’ve got two options as far as I can tell.

Use the trap to either issue a ctrl-c or similar or to somehow use `tput` to move the cursor around and manually redraw the prompt.

So how can I best redraw the prompt when a window resize happens?

Comment: This question is rather confusedly written, with the antecedents for "they" being kitty and iTerm.  Your terminal emulator program does not output the prompt.  Your _shell_ does.

Comment: Good point, I edited it out now.

Comment: I can't give enough shout outs to `tmux` which does this by default and is a giant productivity booster (once you got into it)

Comment: @Panki yes tmux is great but it won't help with this.

Comment: In my tests in Bash 4.4.12 and 4.4.20 the prompt gets redrawn but before `echo`. The following command fixes the issue without triggering a chain reaction: `trap 'echo "$COLUMNS"; kill -s SIGWINCH "$$"' WINCH`. I tested some older versions, they behave differently. In particular the chain reaction occurs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sadly `bash` is also too old on MacOS, so the chain reaction occurs there, too.